# Foreground service doesn't send notifications (API33)

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications, foreground-service

I'm trying to build an Android foreground service on Java. Mostly, it works well, but no notifications appear on my phone during tests (Redmi Note 10 Pro, Android 13).

Please, highlight what is done wrong:

```
public class MyScannerService extends Service {

    private final int MY_SERVICE_ID = 1;
    public static final String MY_CHANNEL_ID = "SERVICE_CHANNEL_ID";
    public static final String MY_CHANNEL_NAME = "Service Channel";
    public static final String ACTION_START_SERVICE = "START_MY_SERVICE";
    public static final String ACTION_STOP_SERVICE = "STOP_MY_SERVICE";

    private AtomicBoolean _isServiceStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private Waiter _waiter = null;

    public MyScannerService () {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("onBind() called. Binding not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(): The service has been created");

        _waiter = new Waiter();

        Notification notification = createNotification();
        startForeground(MY_SERVICE_ID, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy(): The service has been destroyed");

        _isServiceStarted.set(false);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand(): Intent requested action: " + action);

            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_START_SERVICE:
                    startService();
                    break;
                case ACTION_STOP_SERVICE:
                    stopService();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand(): ERROR! Unsupported action requested by the intent!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand(): Null intent received (probably system restart)");
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(MY_CHANNEL_ID, MY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("My test channel");
        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.setSound(null, null);
        channel.setShowBadge(true);
        channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        //channel.enableVibration(true);
        //channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, MY_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("My Service scream")
                .setContentText("Some important text...")
                .setTicker("My ticker")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_clock)          // Just vector icon in res/drawable (ic_clock.xml)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                //.setOngoing(true)
                //.setAutoCancel(false)
                .build();

        return notification;
    }

    private void startService() {

        if (_isServiceStarted.get())
            return;

        _isServiceStarted.set(true);

        _waiter.waiterThread.start();

        Log.d(TAG, "startService(): Service started");
    }

    private void stopService() {

        if (!_isServiceStarted.get())
            return;

        try {
            stopForeground(STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE);
            stopSelf();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "stopService(): Exception occurred during service stopping: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        _isServiceStarted.set(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "stopService(): Service stopped");
    }
}
```

Waiter class is trivial, it just writes messages to the system log and tries to send more notifications:

```
    private class Waiter implements Runnable {

        Thread waiterThread;

        Waiter() {
            waiterThread = new Thread(this, "Just a test thread to monitor service work");
        }

        public void run() {

            while (_isServiceStarted.get())
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Waiter still waits...");

                Notification notification = createNotification();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Client app starts the service this way:

```
    private void runService() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Starting service");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyScannerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(MyScannerService.ACTION_START_SERVICE);
        startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

        Log.d(TAG, "Started");
    }

    private void stopService() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping service");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyScannerService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(MyScannerService.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE);
        startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

        Log.d(TAG, "Stopped");
    }
```

Manifest looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PerfTest"
        tools:targetApi="33">
        <service
            android:name=".MyScannerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.ifa.perftest'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ifa.perftest"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.8.1'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-android")
}
```

So, the service creates and starts, as well as Waiter thread does, I get the next output:

```
D/ClientApp: Starting service
D/ClientApp: Started
D/MyService: onCreate(): The service has been created
D/MyService: onStartCommand(): Intent requested action: START_MY_SERVICE
D/MyService: startService(): Service started
D/MyService: Waiter still waits...
D/MyService: Waiter still waits...
D/MyService: Waiter still waits...
D/ClientApp: Stopping service
D/ClientApp: Stopped
D/MyService: onStartCommand(): Intent requested action: STOP_MY_SERVICE
D/MyService: stopService(): Service stopped
D/MyService: onDestroy(): The service has been destroyed
```

...but no any notifications got

Answer (score 2):

It turned out it just needed the manual permissions request handling.
AFAIK it's Android 13 requirement.

If someone else needs, I used the next code:

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
            if (!isGranted)
                logMessageEverywhere("WARNING: Push notifications disabled!", true);
        });

....
....

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)            
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
```